# Moving JavaFX Nodes Between Stages

Tags: tabs, javafx, move, stage

I'm rewriting a Swing application in JavaFX, where I allow users to present multiple workspaces as either windows or tabs. However, my FX code will not display the contents moved from more than one tab into a new stage; only the contents of the currently-selected tab appear in my new stages. I've distilled my code into a small example below. Can anyone clue me in as to what's gone wrong?

```
package scenes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class StageSwapper extends Application {

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private TabPane tabs = new TabPane();    

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Stage Swapper");
        BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
        p.setCenter(tabs);
        tabs.getTabs().addAll(new Swapee("First").createTab(), new Swapee("Second").createTab());
        Scene s = new Scene(p);
        stage.setScene(s);
        stage.show();
        launchSwap();
    }

    private void launchSwap() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        for (Swapee s : Swapee.list) {
                            createWindow(s);
                        }
                    }                   
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void createWindow(Swapee s) {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.setTitle("New Window");
        window.setY(200);
        window.setX(200);
        BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
        p.setCenter(s);
        window.setScene(new Scene(p));
        window.show();
    }

}

class Swapee extends Label {

    static private int count;
    static ArrayList<Swapee> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String name;

    Swapee(String name) {
        super("Swappable Item " + ++count);
        this.name = name;
        list.add(this);
    }

    Tab createTab() {
        Tab t = new Tab(name);
        t.setContent(this);
        return t;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the size of the windows that you're creating. Right now they have width and length equal to 0. You may use the following approach:

```
BorderPane p = new BorderPane();
p.setPrefSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
p.setCenter(s);
```

BorderPane will be resized according to its content and the window will be resized as well.

Comment: I tried adding the size specification, no change. However, I did notice that after the new windows display (they can be resized to show the content area) selecting the existing tabs on the original stage will display the label in the new window-- and hide the other one that was previously displayed. I'm sure I must not be telling the tab pane that the label was removed from the tab, but I'm not sure how to do that. Setting the tab to null in this example seems to make things worse.

Comment: The thing which is wrong in  your code is that yor add one Node twice to the SceneGraph. You need to provide one Label for table view and another for the Stage.                                    `Tab createTab() {
        Tab t = new Tab(name);
        t.setContent(new Label(name));
        return t;
    }`

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to move the node between stages, for when users decide they'd rather view their GUIs in windows than tabs, and vice versa; something they're used to doing in their Swing apps currently. The components in question are considerably more complex than labels, and I was hoping to avoid re-creating everything.

Comment: As I think all you have to do is to pick the tab content, remove it from the tab and then make it the root of the SceneGraph in the new Window. When the window closes, put it back again. But don't try to use one node in two places simultaneously. See the [example](https://gist.github.com/zinch84/9837767)